# Compliling C++ program in Visual Studio using g++ compiler generates % at the end

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, compiler-errors

When compiling my program in Visual Studio Code using the g++ compiler, the output generated has the `%` sign.

```c
#include <iostream>

int Main() {
  std::cout << "Hello World!";
  return 0;
}
```

Terminal screenshot:

[image: here]

I have deleted the question mark, so I think there is no control character.

Comment: Please include your code as a [formatted code block](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) instead of an image.

Comment: I suspect the `%` after your output is your terminal's prompt, because you don't `endl` after you `cout`. Did you hit enter once after your program finished running?

Comment: Add another `cout` line with `std::endl` at the end and on the `Hello` line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[On POSIX compliant systems, individual lines are by convention delimited by a newline character.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/729795/1968) zsh (which is the shell you’re using) uses `%` to indicate output that’s missing that terminating newline character.

Try entering `echo -n hello` on your shell to replicate the behaviour.

To fix this (and remove the `%` output), add a newline to your code’s output:

```
…
std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
…
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you writing this on a *nix system? You are not printing a end-of-line after "hello world", so the % symbol is likely your command-line prompt.

Comment: The prompt tells you which system it is: macOS.

Comment: The prompt indicates what *shell* you're using, which is not the same thing. And technically macOS is a *nix system.

Comment: I mean, the prompt indicates whatever you want it to indicate. *OP’s* prompt (in the screenshot — click on the link) shows the *system* they’re using (technically the computer name), not the shell. And OP’s shell (zsh) indeed uses `%` as the prompt terminator by default but the `%` being displayed after the output isn’t part of the prompt, it’s what zsh displays when there’s no newline.